# Lof JSliderNews jQuery - how to pause on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

```
jQuery(function($) {

            var buttons = {
                 previous: jQuery('#lofslidecontent45 .lof-previous'),
                 next: jQuery('#lofslidecontent45 .lof-next')
             };

            window.setTimeout(function(){
         $obj = jQuery('#lofslidecontent45').lofJSidernews({
                 interval: 4000,
                 direction: 'opacitys',
                 easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
                 duration: 1200,
                 auto: true,
                 maxItemDisplay: 3,
                 navPosition: 'horizontal', // horizontal
                 navigatorHeight: 40,
                 navigatorWidth: 70,
                 mainWidth: 1000,
                 buttons: buttons,
                 isPreloaded:false
                });  
            },500);


         });
```

How to configure pause on hover?
is there any reference for this slider?
or is there any option like hover: stop?

Comment: This can be helpful for you to customize the control for yourself http://rtl-this.com/tutorial/lof-jslidernews-jquery-plugin-now-rtl-support

Comment: This one stops on hover http://rtl-this.com/sites/default/files/demos/lofslidernews/index.html

Comment: i mean any config option like hover:stop,?

Answer (score 0):

there is no such config like `hover: "stop"`.
But if you look in the actual `.js` file, you will find

```
$( obj ).hover(function(){
    self.stop();    
    $buttonControl.addClass("action-start").removeClass("action-stop").addClass("hover-stop");
}, function(){
    if( $buttonControl.hasClass("hover-stop") ){    
        if( self.settings.auto ){
            $buttonControl.removeClass("action-start").removeClass("hover-stop").addClass("action-stop");
                self.play( self.settings.interval,'next', true );       
        }
    }
} );
```

That means, hover stop functionality is default there.